# Problema con simulador de dado python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

Pues soy nuevo en esto de programar y como ejercicio quise hacer un simulador de dado (si ya se que se puede hacer en menos lineas de código pero esto lo quise hacer con mi conocimiento osea a ciegas) pues el único problema que tengo es que el resultado que quiero que imprima cuando salga el 6 nunca lo hace y en su lugar imprime el resultado de 'Mejor suerte la proxima'

```
maximo = 6
inicio = 1
azar = 0
comando = ""
while True:
    comando = input('Te gustaria probar tu suerte? ').lower()
    if comando == 'si':
        print('Ahi vamos!')
        import random
        azar = print(random.randint(inicio, maximo))
        if azar == maximo:
            print('Felicidades Ganaste!')
        else:
            print('Mejor suerte la proxima!')
    elif comando == 'no':
        print('Oh que pena :')
    elif comando == 'cerrar':
        print('Adios!')
break
```

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @nicolás-ruiz? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 1):

La función `print()` **no devuelve nada**; puedes verlo con un sencillo ejemplo:

```
print( print( "hola mundo !" ) )
```

> hola, mundo !
>   None

Por lo tanto, tu código debería quedar así:

```
...
azar = random.randint( inicio, maximo )
print( azar )
...
```